# How to solve the error AFTER setup an ubuntu in my pc

Tags: 12.04, boot, windows

I have windows 7 my computer. Now i tried to install ubuntu 12.04 in my pc. after installting the ubuntu pc suddenly took restart and after that i see this image on my screen, when the pc starts. is there any way to solve this?  i can not go into my windows 7 too. [image]

EDIT:

now i have inserted the ubuntu dvd to set up again.i go to the boot option and i clicked F12 but same erroor appears again. [image]

EDIT AGAIN:

After using the "try ubuntu" i got  this display [image]

I wrote the terminal as you suggested. Where to find the Ubuntu repair now/. ?

Comment: This is the fix for you http://askubuntu.com/questions/139121/grub-rescue-prompt-after-install-installing-ubuntu-in-a-dual-boot

Comment: i can not go to my ubuntu due to the error. after starting the pc i only see the the eoor i attached. and i cAN open the boot menu by typing the F2

Comment: Did you even read the link ? Make a DVD or USB and choose try ubuntu and follow the instructions

Comment: i can not go to the ubuntu back so how can i give order into the terminal?  i am trying to set up the pc by windows 7 but even it is not working too and it shows the error message i attached.  can u please tell  me details what to do,

Comment: when i do anything in my pc in the boot menu. then it shows the error i attached in the picture.

Comment: Boot from the CD or DVD or USB you installed Ubuntu from and choose"try ubuntu", this will give you a desktop so you can enter the commands

Comment: sorry, where from i choose the "try ubuntu"?

Comment: When you boot from your live CD/DVD/USB it will ask if you want to install ubuntu or try ubuntu, you want to try ubuntu

Comment: when i insert the ubuntu cd, i can see the two option. one is the error message and otherwise i can go to the boot option by clicking F2  ..  even i tried to formAt by using windows 7 but i see the error message3 GAIN AND AGAIN. I CANT SEE ANY OPTION SO I CAN WORK WITH UBUNTU.

Comment: Do you have a USB or a CD of Ubuntu

Comment: YES I HAVE A UBUNTU DVD AND I  used the dvd to installl the ubuntu in my pc.

Comment: OK put that dvd in the drive and boot from the dvd, if it wont work go to your bios and set it

Comment: i see the error message again

Comment: check the edit please

Comment: Move the dvd to the top of that list then reboot. dont for get to save it

Comment: thanks , i can see the ubuntu now . you are great. will i install the ubuntu now?

Comment: No, bear with me I will write a guide for you

Comment: possible duplicate of [After update, get "error: file not found." followed by "grub rescue> \_"](http://askubuntu.com/questions/187862/after-update-get-error-file-not-found-followed-by-grub-rescue)

Comment: possible duplicate of [HELP! Grub Rescue Mode](http://askubuntu.com/questions/322425/help-grub-rescue-mode)

Answer (score 1):

OK boot your live DVD and choose try Ubuntu, press the ubuntu button (top left) and open a terminal and enter these commands, one at a time.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair

sudo sed 's/trusty/saucy/g' -i /etc/apt/sources.list.d/yannubuntu-boot-repair-trusty.list

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && (boot-repair &)
```

When it is finished press the Ubuntu button again and search for boot repair, run this and choose recommended repair.

Follow any instructions given and when it is finished turn off your PC.

Remove the DVD from the drive, and turn it on, you will see all you oSs in a list after bios.

Answer (score -1):

use a bootable usb with boot repair, or install boot repair using ubuntu live usb, https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair this link has the details

alternatively if you have a windows disk try this
http://www.tweakhound.com/2012/11/13/how-to-fix-the-windows-bootloader/

good luck

Comment: You cant make a bootable disk with boot-repair

Comment: sorry, was in a hurry

Comment: CAN'T I GIVE FORMAT BY USING WINDOWS DISK THEN I CAN INSTALL THE UBUNTU AGAIN/?

Comment: yes, but you are gonna lose all your data